# How does revision history work? Side-by-side comparison not showing up for a random revision history entry

Tags: discussion, bug

I was looking at the [revision history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/47583/revisions) for [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47583/why-does-the-media-continue-to-hide-the-identity-of-the-trump-ukraine-whistle-bl) question here:

For revision 11 I can see the comment

```
Added proper name.
```

But I cannot see anything else. Shouldn't it show a side by side comaprison of what has been changed? I can see such a comparison for the other history entries. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like for me:

[image]

Is this a browser thing? I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: I saw that too. Based on the edit description, I'm thinking the revision might have been deleted if it was an attempt to dox someone.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it's possible to edit revision history? What's the point of having it then? Or is it a moderator only feature?

Comment: I know that moderators can delete some or all of the revision history. Not exactly sure how it works, but it's typically used to remove personal information from the edit history.

Answer (score 4):

That question was flagged because the revision history included the supposed name of the person the question was about, and apparently, that name is being kept hidden, so I figured we might as well be on the save side and not have the name in the question.